# How can I open the Edge browser with Selenium to maintain login status

Tags: python, selenium, browser, microsoft-edge

I am now using Selenium to open the Edge browser. It runs fine, but I find that I cannot keep the login status. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep the login status using Selenium because it creates a new profile every time you launch the browser. You can launch Edge with the same profile every time to keep the login status.

Sample code:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True    

#Here you set the path of the profile ending with User Data not the profile folder
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data"); 

#Here you specify the actual profile folder    
edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1");

edge_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
driver = Edge(options = edge_options, executable_path = "your\\path\\to\\edge\\webdriver\\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

The above code uses MS Edge Selenium tools. You need to run the command below to install it:

```
pip install msedge-selenium-tools selenium==3.141
```

Please note to change all the paths in the code to your owns. If you don't know the path of the specific profile, you could check **edge://version/** like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, which solved my problem perfectly